# Why KL Divergence instead of Cross-entropy in VAE

Tags: neural-networks, loss-functions, autoencoders, kullback-leibler, cross-entropy

I understand how KL divergence provides us with a measure of how one probability distribution is different from a second, reference probability distribution. But why is it particularly used (instead of cross-entropy) in generative networks such as Variational Autoencoders (VAEs)? As much as I understand, minimizing either Cross-Entropy or KL-divergence is equivalent. So, I struggle to understand why KL divergence is the preferred loss function in VAEs.

NB: I originally asked this question in Data Science SE and referred to forward it here.

Comment: The last 2 sections on KLD and CE might help you understand for VAE https://medium.com/swlh/cross-entropy-and-kl-divergence-522d9f71bd3d

Comment: related: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/82152/why-kl-divergence-instead-of-cross-entropy-in-vae

Comment: Please don't cross-post. If you feel that another site would be a better fit for the question, flag it for migration.

Comment: KL is not the same as cross entropy; KL is negative self entropy + cross entropy. So minimizing KL has an additional regularizing effect (via the entropy maximization) absent in CE minimization.

Comment: @JohnMadden That seems like the start of a complete answer to the question. Perhaps you could expand it?